# Irreducibility and invariant measure of diffusions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process

I am reading up the textbook *[Stochastic Analysis and Diffusion Processes](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Stochastic_Analysis_and_Diffusion_Proces/1jozAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1)* written by Gopinath Kallianpur and P. Sundar, and am coming up with some questions. Here is the context.

We consider the solution of the $d$-dimensional SDE $$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+dW_t,$$
where $b$ is a smooth vector field on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that the solution does not explode. And here are my questions:

1. In Remark 11.3.1 there is a statement saying that if $\mu$ is an invariant measure of the process $X$, then $\mu$ should have a density.
2. Let $p_t(x,dy)$ be the transition kernel of the process $X$. And assume that the process has an absolutely continuous invariant measure. In the proof the author asserts that the kernel has a density $p_t(x,y)$ and we even have $p_t(x,y)>0$ for almost every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

I am not able to justify these two statements. Could anyone help?